# Regex, string after 2 space

Tags: regex

I would like to take the string after the 2 first space

Example : 
  I have the string : "JUN 15 ME 10Y CDN BND"
  I would like to have "ME 10Y CDN BND"

The length of the string before the 2 space is variable off course.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What language/tool are you using, and do you even need a regex for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is

```
\s\S*\s(.*)
```

Explanation:

- `\s` = Find first space
- `\S` = Find word after space
- `\s` = Find second space
- `(.*)` = Grab everything after the space

Your result will be returned in the first capture group - `(.*)`

Ps. You might be able to get away with a lookbehind - `(?<=\s\S*\s).*` - which returns only the portion you are interested in and avoids having to get the capture group, but not all regex engines support this, as the lookbehind, as you mentioned, is of variable width.